# Verifying a vertex cover in linear time

Tags: algorithm, graph

> Suppose you are given an undirected graph G with n vertices and m
>   edges represented by an adjacency list A, and you are also
>   given a subset of vertices S with size |S| represented by an array. How
>   can you check whether S is a vertex cover of G with O(n + m) time and O(n + m) space complexity?

This is a follow-up question to a question that I posted earlier this week, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59851921/quadratic-time-vertex-cover-verification). It might help to read that post (and the solution) there first.

By the definition of a vertex cover, I know that we require every edge must be incident to a vertex that's contained in S.

I've tried to follow an approach similar to what I posted in the previous thread. In particular, I created an array B[] containing all of the vertices that are in G but not in S. This means that for any two vertices u and v in B, if (u, v) exists, then the vertex cover isn't valid.

But I'm pretty sure this algorithm is n^2, not n + m since if S is the empty set, then B will contain all vertices, and if G is the complete graph, then checking whether (u, v) exists is an `O(n^2)` operation.

I was wondering if there is a nice solution to this problem.

Thanks

Comment: If you're starting with an adjacency matrix, you can't possibly know you have a vertex cover without checking all the cells.  Any cell you don't look at might be an edge you need to cover.

Comment: That's better I guess, but then just like the other thread, I don't know why you aren't just checking every edge to see if its vertices are in S.  That should be a constant time check.  If it's not, then you have plenty of time to convert S into a better representation.

Comment: I would like to solve the problem without hashing, so it is a linear time check. I edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: No need to hash.  Just make an array A of n Booleans, so that A[v] = true iff v is in S

Comment: Okay, I can do that. I had something similar to this before, but then here's what I did next: for each vertex `u` in `A` , iterate over all vertices `v` in `Adj[u],` and check whether `u == v` holds. If so, return `false`. At the end of the loop, return  `true`. This works, but I'm pretty sure it runs in `O(n^2)` time, doesn't it? Maybe I'm just not seeing another clever way to do this.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  You need to check all the edges in G, to see if their adjacent vertices are in S.  `for v = 1 to n { for u in Adj[v] { if (!A[v] && !A[u]) return false} } return true`